# How can I delete data from two tables that have a relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[i have this database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpgZD.png)

i want to delete fax in Fax table and records in FaxData that have the same id of fax in Fax table 
i created viewmodel view to connect the 2 tables 
     using System.Web.Mvc;

```
namespace FaxProject.ViewModel
{
public class SendFaxVm
{

    public List<SelectListItem> Employees { set; get; }

    public int[] SelectedEmployees { set; get; }
    public Fax fax { set; get; }
    public int FaxId { set; get; }
    public string CompanyName { set; get; }
    public int Courier_Num { set; get; }
    public Nullable<int> NumberOfPages { get; set; }

    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
    public string ReceivingDate { get; set; }
    public string Attachment { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }

}
}
```

this is the viewmodel

```
  public ActionResult Delete(int id,SendFaxVm vm,Fax fax)
    {
        foreach (var userId in vm.SelectedEmployees)
        {
            var faxdatadelete = Db.FaxDatas.Single(f => f.FaxId == fax.Id);
            Db.FaxDatas.Remove(faxdatadelete);

            Db.SaveChanges();
        }

        var deletedfax = Db.Faxes.Single(f => f.Id == id);
        Db.Faxes.Remove(deletedfax);
        Db.SaveChanges();






        return RedirectToAction("FaxForm", "Fax");
    }
```

and this is the action in fax controller .....
and this is the exception that i got when i try to delete (An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in FaxProject.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Comment: plz provide more detailed information, e.g. where the exception is thrown

Comment: at this line (foreach (var userId in vm.SelectedEmployees))

Comment: so I suppose SendFaxVm vm is null, no SendFaxVm is passed

*one hint, learn how to debug and how to work with breakpoints

Comment: seems one of the .Single() returns null, you need to check it.

Comment: Can you not set the database to Cascade Delete and then let Entity Framework deal with the relationships directly?

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id, SendFaxVm vm, Fax fax)
{
    if (SendFaxVm == null || Fax == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("FaxForm", "Fax");
    }

    foreach (var userId in vm.SelectedEmployees)
    {
        var faxdatadelete = Db.FaxDatas.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FaxId == fax.Id);
        if (faxdatadelete != null)
        {
            Db.FaxDatas.Remove(faxdatadelete);
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    var deletedfax = Db.Faxes.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);
    if (deletedfax != null)
    {
        Db.Faxes.Remove(deletedfax);
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("FaxForm", "Fax");
}
```

Comment: the same exception :(